# GMP: get the absolute value of the difference?

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gmp

I need maximum performances using GMP and I wonder whether there is a better way to compute the absolute value of the difference of two numbers.
Currently I use:

```
mpz_sub(x, a, b);
mpz_abs(x, x);
```

Is there a most efficient way to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure that performance suffers from GMP functions? Did you try to profile your code? And no, I haven't hear about faster way.

Comment: You could use [`mpz_sign`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Comparisons.html) on the result of the subtraction, though I don't know how efficient that would be.

Comment: Seems to me that it is fairly close to optimal (mpz_abs only does a trivial sign operation when source==dest).

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Thanks, I didn't know that. If this is the case, this is in fact close to optimal.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: make that an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code should already be close to optimal. When the source and destination are the same, `mpz_abs` takes constant time: it does not read the big number and only performs a trivial operation on the sign.